# Copy Text from Table in Word and Retaing Formatting

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a problem copying a cell from a table to another cell. I'm talking about two word documents here. I can copy the text but the bullets are gone and some of the formatting.

I tried `.Formattedtext` but still can't do it.

```
Dim test As Word.Cell

'An error occurs something like "Object variable or With block variable not set"
test.Range.FormattedText = CTPDoc.Tables(2).Rows(testCount).Cells(3).Range.FormattedText
```

Comment: Have you tried `Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)`?

Comment: I haven't treid that. How do I use that? I'm sorry I'm new to VBA

Comment: Can you show what have you tried?

Comment: Dim test as word.cell  test.Range.FormattedText = CTPDoc.Tables(2).Rows(testCount).Cells(3).Range.FormattedText  an error occurs something like "Object variable or With block variable not set"

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example.

Let's say we have two tables in a word document. See screenshot below

[image]

Let's say we want to paste the data from `Cell 1` of `Table 1` to `Cell 1` of `Table 2` then try this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim tbl1 As Table, tbl2 As Table

    Set tbl1 = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    Set tbl2 = ActiveDocument.Tables(2)

    tbl1.Cell(1, 1).Range.Copy
    tbl2.Cell(1, 1).Range.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
End Sub
```

This is what the macro does

[image]

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I think I can use that with my scenario. The two tables are from different files. My problem is I get all the values first before I open the target file and paste all the values. Thanks

Comment: your above code shows that you are reading the values form a a table so the method that i suggested above will work for you. give it a try

Comment: I have a problem...I thought it's all working now but I tried it in a different computer and an error occurs in .PastandFormat line. It says 'Command not available' :(

Comment: Which MS Office version are you using on that pc?

Comment: I'm using 2010 where I code and 2007 where I tested. I tried different parameters instead of wdFormatOriginalFormatting and some works but the format ia a bit messed up. One worked but in one instance only. I mean when I tried to use different source file the format is messed again.

Comment: I'm currently using wdListContinueNumbering and wdUseDestinationStylesRecovery and it's now working on both computers. I assume it'll work on any other too. Although something's must be wrong with source file causing the messed up format when pasted. Thanks for everything. This is solved :)

Answer (score 1):

@Siddharth Rout
You answer was really helpful. It's not the exact answer to my problem but at least I learned about `PasteandFormat` and its different types such as `wdFormatOriginalFormatting`. maybe someday I can use that.

Now here goes what solved my problem.
Using the logic given by Siddharth, I used the simple `tbl2.Cell(1, 1).Range.Paste` instead of `PasteandFormat`. Actually `PasteandFormat` worked but there was a problem which happens in only selected source file/table. I think there's some formatting that exist in the source table that when pasted in another cell, it'll look messed up. I'm not sure about what exactly what's that but `.Paste` definitely solved it for me. I hoped I can help others too :)