# Copying formatted Word text into Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word, ms-access-2013

I am trying to adapt VBA from this page [copy formatted text into access using vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30805707/copy-formatted-text-into-access-using-vba) so that it loops through all files selected or all files in a specific folder. Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: It is possible, yes. What exactly is your problem? Selecting multiple files with a filepicker? Adapting the code to execute once per file? Selecting all files in a folder with the .doc or .docx extension?

Comment: I'm trying to repeat it for several files rather than having to re-run it for each file. I amended AllowMultiSelect = True but would like to run it for all those files selected, or all the files in a specific folder, whichever is easiest. Sorry, I'm fairly new to all this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one of two things: don't split the filepicker function and the import function, or return a collection or an array from your filepicker function.

I'm going to choose the latter for educational value:

**Pick the files**

```
Public Function FilesToOpen() As Collection

    ' This function will essentially allow you to browse to MS-Word document
    ' and then store the path of that file for use in the GetWordContent function

    Dim fDialog As Object 'Office.FileDialog
    Dim varFile As Variant

    Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(3)
    Set FilesToOpen = New Collection
    With fDialog
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Title = "Select Word document to import"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Word files", "*.doc?"

        If _
            .Show = True _
        Then
            For Each varFile In .SelectedItems
                FilesToOpen.Add varFile
            Next
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

**And open them**

```
Private Sub cmdGetWordData_Click()

    ' This subroutine runs on your command button; it will call both the FileToOpen function and GetWordContent subroutine
    ' to retrieve the text contents of your chosen MS-Word Document.
    ' It will then store both the path the text contents of of your chosen MS-Word Document in 2 fields in a table in Access.

    ' NOTE: this code assumes that your Access database has:
    ' - a table called tblWordDump
    ' - a memo text field in this table called WordDocDataSrc to store the path of MS-Word file imported
    ' - a memo text field in this table called WordDocData with the TextFormat property set to "Rich Text",
    '   which will store the text and text formating of the MS-Word file imported

    Dim collFiles As Collection
    Dim strWordContent As Variant

    ' Select files via File Dialogue

    Set collFiles = FilesToOpen
    Dim oneFile As Variant

    ' Conditionals when a file was or wasn't selected

    If _
        collFiles.Count <> 0 _
    Then
        For Each oneFile In collFiles

            DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec

            GetWordContent CStr(oneFile)
        Next oneFile

        MsgBox "Import Successful", vbInformation Or vbOKOnly

    Else

        MsgBox "No File Selected", vbExclamation Or vbOKOnly

    End If

End Sub
```

Note that I attempted to change as little as possible and have not done anything with the `GetWordContent` function.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm getting "Compile error: ByRef argument type mismatch" on GetWordContent oneFile.

Comment: Oh, that's just Access being picky.  `GetWordContent CStr(oneFile)` should do. Edited answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks. I'm now getting Run-time error '424' on Set collFiles = FilesToOpen.

Comment: Eh... you shouldn't. I've tested the code, and it's valid. Sometimes Access is even more picky and requires parentheses like this: `Set collFiles = FilesToOpen()` but it doens't here (Access 2016)